# elasticsearch synonyms not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

The text I'm trying to search is `2 marina blvd`, the result returned by elasticsearch (top 3) are:

```
2 MARINA GREEN, SINGAPORE 019800
MARINA BAYFRONT 2 RAFFLES LINK, SINGAPORE 039392
THE SAIL @ MARINA BAY 2 MARINA BOULEVARD, SINGAPORE 018987
```

In my synonyms list, `blvd` is same as `boulevard`.

When I search `2 marina blvd`, I'm expecting this `THE SAIL @ MARINA BAY 2 MARINA BOULEVARD, SINGAPORE 018987` will be the one at the top with highest score, since `2 marina blvd` equals to `2 marina boulevard`. But now `2 MARINA GREEN, SINGAPORE 019800` is on top.

What went wrong, how can I improve my search result?

The full settings are:

```
{
  "geolocation": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1471322099847",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "my_synonym_filter": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms": [
                "rd,road",
                "ave,avenue",
                "blvd,boulevard",
                "st,street",
                "lor,lorong",
                "ter,terminal",
                "blk,block",
                "apt,apartment",
                "condo,condominium"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "my_synonyms": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "my_synonym_filter"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "stopwords_analyzer": {
              "type": "standard",
              "stopwords": [
                "the"
              ]
            },
            "my_ngram_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ],
              "min_gram": "2",
              "type": "nGram",
              "max_gram": "5"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "mPfZmWHFQZOHqfAi471nGQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030599"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the query

```
body: {
      from : 0, size : 10,
      query: {
        bool: {
          should: [
            {
              match: {
                text: q
              }
            },
            {
              match: {
                text: {
                  query: q,
                  fuzziness: 1,
                  prefix_length: 0,
                  max_expansions: 100
                }
              }
            },
            {
              match: {
                text: {
                  query: q,
                  max_expansions: 300,
                  type: "phrase_prefix"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

And the mapping is:

```
{
  "geolocation": {
    "mappings": {
      "location": {
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "blk": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "building": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "postalCode": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "road": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "searchText": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "x": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "y": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And the mapping for the `text` field please

Comment: @AndreiStefan Updated

Comment: Hm... none of your fields are using your analyzer...

Comment: @AndreiStefan so how should I set the analyzer, any documentation or examples?

Comment: Just use `"searchText": {
            "type": "string", "analyzer":"my_synonyms"
          }`. And you need to re-create the index, of course, and to re-index all the documents.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks, I'm trying.

Comment: @AndreiStefan how can I apply multiple analyzers to one field?

Comment: You can't. One analyzer for search and one for indexing time, that's all you can do.

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes, it works! this is the analyzer for indexing time, how to use analyzer so that I can benefit from query time?

Comment: But, you can add subfields for which you can define other analyzers and do the search on those as well.

Comment: Most of the times the analyzer at indexing time can be the same at search time. There are fewer cases where another analyzer is needed at search time. By default (when using `"analyzer": "whatever_analyzer"`) the same analyzer is used at searching and indexing time.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Great! thanks a loootttt!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined analyzers but you haven't set any of them for your fields.
The most basic setup would be:

```
"searchText": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer":"my_synon‌​yms"
}
```

One field can have one analyzer for indexing time and one at searching time. Most of the use cases usually use the same analyzer at indexing and searching time. By default (when using `"analyzer": "whatever_analyzer"‌​`) the same analyzer is used at searching and indexing time.

To get more insight into analysis and what you can do with, please consult
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/analysis-intro.html.

Comment: How can I apply synonyms, phonetic, stop-word, ngram filters together on one field with the limitation of one field only one filter.